# Error on “npm install socket.io” version 1.0.0

Tags: node.js, npm, socket.io, node-modules

i want to install socket.io version 1.0.0 but  npm gives me the error "version not found"

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible not to publish every incremental version of an package. It is possible that version 1.0.0 was never published, therefor you cannot install it. try:

```
$npm install@1.0.1
```